# Mysql Inner Join multiple

Tags: mysql, join

So i have 3 tables. 
First table has 2 foreign keys and inside a foreign key has other one.

(sorry for bad english)

Example:

```
First table: table1
Foreign keys: 
ID from table1 (I will get the employee name)
ID from table2 (I will get the job name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing one of your `JOINs`:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_job_site.JOB_NAME, 
    tbl_employee.EMP_CODIGO, 
    tbl_company.COM_CODIGO
FROM tbl_job_running jr
   INNER JOIN tbl_employee e ON jr.EMP_CODIGO = e.EMP_CODIGO
   INNER JOIN tbl_job_site js ON jr.JOB_CODIGO = js.JOB_CODIGO
   INNER JOIN tbl_company c ON c.COM_CODIGO = e.COM_CODIGO
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)